# Вытащить определенные буквы из строки

Tags: c++

Из строки `std::string` нужно вытащить 2, 3 и 4 символы, к примеру. Как это сделать, не прибегая к `c_str()` ?

Comment: `std::string s = "test"; char c = s[3];`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По вопросу не совсем понятно, нужно ли получить отдельные символы или подстроку.
Для отдельных символов `std::string` есть `operator[]`

```
std::string s = "test";
char c = s[3]; // c == 't'
```

для подстроки - `std::string::substr`

```
std::string s = "test";
size_t start = 1, length = 3;
std::string r = s.substr(start, length); // r == "est"
```

Comment: @neko69 Единственное - не забудьте убедиться, что строка достаточно длинная, что в ней есть `s[3]`, например.

Comment: @Harry для неуверенных подойдет 'at()'